# popToRootController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've created the following storyboard:

> - Navigation Controller
>
>   - Login View Controller
>
>     - Tab Controller
>     - Navigation Controller
>
>       - Search View Controller
>
>         - Results View Controller
>
>           - Detail View Controller
>     - Navigation Controller
>
>       - Advanced Search View Controller
>
>         - Results View Controller
>
>           - Detail View Controller

When the user taps a tab bar button I want to make sure that the view they see is the Search (if they tapped Search) or Advanced Search (if they tapped Advanced) not the point in the stack they might have previously been on for a given tab.  In other words, I want to have them start at the top/root view

I've set the tab bar's delegate to a class and implemented the didSelectViewController as:

Tab bar controller .h

```
#import <UIKit /UIKit.h>
@interface TabController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Tab bar controller .m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In both the Search and Advanced Search Controller .m

```
- (void) viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Hide the nav bar at the search/advanced controller level.  Will be shown at results and detail levels
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    //Set the text for the back button
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"title" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
}
```

The result is that when the user taps the Advanced Search button nothing appears but a black screen.  Comment out that code and the Advanced Search is properly displayed.

Note that the Results and Detail Controllers are reused for both the search and advanced searches.

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.  If a keep banging my head against this wall I won't have to buy a halloween costume!

Comment: Any other code you can show us?  It's pretty hard to see with just a flow chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same kind of issue. I have used this code and it worked.`[(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: L3ST3R, That worked!  2 days of pulling hair (what little I have left).  Thank you!